# WordPress newbie here - should I be using child or parent themes?

Tags: wordpress, parent-child

I've just got started on editing WordPress code and have a very basic question.

I've been editing on WordPress all along using plugins and frontend editors. However, I've started to dig into the source code to develop my website further and have thus installed a child theme.

Question is - and I've been searching all over the internet for answers - when I continue to make edits using plugins and frontend editors, should I continue to use the parent theme or child theme? I would think I should use the parent theme - am I right? A child theme is used purely for custom code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Advantages of Using a WordPress Child Theme

• a child theme will remain untouched when updating WordPress or the parent theme. You will lose all changes made to the parent theme when it gets updated.

• Extend functionality. You can selectively extend the functions you need without touching anything else.

Disadvantages of Using a Child Theme

• Time investment. When you are first starting out with child themes, you need to take the time to learn about WordPress frameworks and their individual filters & hooks.

Child themes also enable folks to customize a parent theme themselves without touching any core files, a practice that safeguards those customization when performing updates to the parent theme. So it is better to use a child theme if there require editing core files.

Comment: Thanks alot melvin. 1 more question - so I've added some php code to my child theme functions.php file but it's not reflecting in my parent theme. What can I do to ensure that all changes made in the child theme reflect in the parent theme?

Comment: If you find the answer helpful please either mark it as answer or upvote@M.Tang

Comment: @M.Tang . Check if your child theme is active. Your child theme should be active instead of parent theme.  Child theme is an extended version of  your parent theme. So  your changes can be seen on the front end. Also check whether you used the correct hook .